# Why we cannot use least squares method to estimate the parameters of a logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, estimation, maximum-likelihood, least-squares

I recently read about logistic regression model.
$$
y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\beta_1x)}}.
$$
What seems to be perplexing to me is, I can see different optimization tools being used to estimate the parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.

[Here,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) maximum likelihood based estimation technique has been used.
Whereas we could have simply used the least square based technique to estimate the parameter.

Can you please tell which one is the best method to estimate parameters for logistic regression and why?

Comment: @Dave, right. I was posting an answer for a different version of the question. It was about MLE vs. SGD. I wonder why I cannot find it in the version history of the post. I was quite sure it involved SGD, but I cannot find that! Or perhaps I am just mistaken.

Comment: Like weighted least squares, MLE implicitly weights observations differently, giving more accurate parameter estimates. Try using a simulation where the response probabilities range from very small to values around .5 for your X values, and compare accuracy of OLS vs MLE over 1000s of replications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Least squares estimates, when the outcome variable Y=0, 1, will result in some predicted probabilities that are negative or greater than 1.0.  As these are illegal values, this is not good performance to say the least.  Maximum likelihood estimates (of which least squares is an example only for normally distributed continuous Y) are guaranteed to be efficient as $N \rightarrow \infty$.  Not only will MLEs be efficient but they respect the structure of the problem by restricting estimated probabilities to be in $[0,1]$.

So think of it this way: Always use MLEs (or penalized MLEs or Bayesian estimates which are also based on the likelihood function).  In the case of conditionally normally distributed Y (normal residuals) the MLEs happen to be the least squares estimates.  The equivalence in the special Gaussian case stems from the fact that the log likelihood function is proportional to the sum of squared errors plus a constant.

Comment: I took the question to mean minimizing Brier score. While that would not be an MLE, all predictions would be legal.

Comment: Oh yes.  In that case you are right they would all be legal, just not statistically efficient.

Comment: Is that the only reason to prefer minimizing log loss to minimizing Brier score, that the latter requires a larger sample size to get confidence intervals that are equally tight?

Comment: Many reasons - narrower confidence limits, lower mean squared error of predicted probabilities, ability to add penalty terms to the log likelihood, ability to add a prior to the log-likelihood to do a Bayesian analysis, extension to longitudinal data, extension to multinomial and ordinal data, formal hypothesis tests.

Comment: Instead of lower MSE of predicted probabilities I'd say ability to estimate partial effects and get confidence intervals for them.